# Como capturo o texto de uma página web com Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Preciso criar um Gerador de Pessoas padrão utilizando o site https://www.4devs.com.br/gerador_de_pessoas com o Selenium.
Esse é o código que eu tenho por enquanto:

```
 [TestFixture]  
 public class GeradorDePessoas
 {
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.4devs.com.br/gerador_de_pessoas");
    }

    [Test]
    public void DeveGerarUmaPessoa()
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("sexo")).Click();

        SelectElement idade = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("idade")));
        idade.SelectByValue("20");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("pontuacao")).Click();

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("bt_gerar_pessoa")).Click();


        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='nome']"));
    }

}
```

O meu problema agora é que eu preciso capturar as informações geradas pelo site e colocá-las em variáveis no programa para que elas possam ser chamadas posteriormente em outros testes.  Alguém pode me ajudar com isso? Não faço ideia de qual caminho tomar a partir de agora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='nome']")).text;
```